# Accessing variables in a function in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if it is possible to **simplify the code** of the following function (i.e, if the part of the code: *d0 =  p$d0, d11 = p$d11, d12 = p$d12, k11 = p$k11, k12 = p$k12* can be replaced by some function) as I am just accessing the variables passed to the function trough the list p.

This is the R code of the function:

```
equation = function(p){

  d0 =  p$d0
  d11 = p$d11
  d12 = p$d12
  k11 = p$k11
  k12 = p$k12

  result = d0 + d11*k11 + d12*k12

  return(result)
}

equation(list(d0=1,d11=2,d12=3,k11=100,k12=1000))
```

Comment: Well you don't need to assign them to local variables.  `p$d0 + p$d11*p$k11 + p$d12*p$k12` could be the entire body of your function.

Comment: @Dason please suggest this as an answer before something more complicated (rather than simpler) gets accepted...

Comment: `equation <- function(p) return(with(p, d0 + d11*k11 + d12*k12))`

Comment: @Spacedman I didn't write it as an answer because I didn't think the question was entirely appropriate. Seems more like a code review type thing.  But I guess I'll put it as an answer since I do think it's probably the best approach for this particular problem and the other answers I'm not really a fan of.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer rather than editing it into your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I am new in stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for anything fancy.  You don't have enough that typing the `p$` in front of each is overly burdensome and you don't need to assign anything locally.  `return` isn't required so we can actually write your function with a single line body as:

```
equation <- function(p){
    p$d0 + p$d11*p$k11 + p$d12*p$k12
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass your elements as function arguments :

```
equation <- function(d0, d11, d12, k11, k12){
  d0 + d11*k11 + d12*k12
}

equation( d0=1, d11=2, d12=3, k11=100, k12=1000)
[1] 3201
```

Colin

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `zeallot` package, which has the unpacking assignment `%<-%`:

```
library(zeallot)

equation = function(p){
  c(d0, d11, d12, k11, k12) %<-% p

  result = d0 + d11*k11 + d12*k12

  return(result)
}

equation(list(d0=1,d11=2,d12=3,k11=100,k12=1000))
## 3201
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using list2env(p, envir = environment())

```
equation = function(p){

  list2env(p, envir = environment())

  result = d0 + d11*k11 + d12*k12

  return(result)
}
```

equation(list(d0=1,d11=2,d12=3,k11=100,k12=1000))